# Compiler Error: Cannot convert from 'List<string>' to 'IList<object>'

Tags: .net, covariance, c#-5.0

How would I change the following code to make it compile?  (Other than casting/changing `strings` to `List<object>`).

```
Action<IList<object>> DoSomething = (list) => { /*list is never modified*/ };
var strings = new List<string>() { "one", "two" };
DoSomething(strings);
```

Comment: do you really need it to be `IList` (are you just viewing or also modifying the collection) ? What `DoSomething` should do really

Comment: @NSGaga, the IList won't be modified inside "DoSomething".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the compiler error indicates, you can't cast a `IList<string>` to an `IList<object>`. This is because the `IList<T>` interface is *invariant* with respect to `T`. Imagine if your  did something like this:

```
Action<IList<object>> DoSomething = (list) => list.Add(1);
```

This would be valid with a `IList<object>` but not with an `IList<string>`.

As long as you're not trying to modify the collection, a simple solution is to change the `IList<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`, which is *covariant* with respect to `T`:

```
Action<IEnumerable<object>> DoSomething = (list) => { };
var strings = new List<string>() { "one", "two" };
DoSomething(strings);
```

**Further Reading**

- [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Covariance and contravariance (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: Thanks, that does help my understanding better. I marked as answer and see if I can study the articles referenced.  I'll also investigate whether I can change the code from IList to IEnumerable since the collection should never be modified.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new list:

```
DoSomething(strings.OfType<object>().ToList());
```

Or use `Action<IEnumerable<object>>` instead, if you can.

Comment: 1. I would use `Cast` instead of `OfType` here, because you don't actually want to do any filtering. 2. You can get rid of the `OfType` completely by writing just  `strings.ToList<object>()`.